# How to count a fixed no of lines in a large file using bufferedreader in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I need to read a large file containing few million lines. Now when I am reading the whole file, the buffer becomes very heavy and some times throws memory exception.

So what I want is, for example I have 10000 lines. I want to read till 1000 lines, process it and then again read from 1001 till 2000 and so on until end. Any help would be highly appreciated.

What I have do now

```
String filePath="some path";
log.debug("File name got for promo ::::::   "+filePath);
File f = new File(filePath);
int i = 0;

try {
    System.out.println("Reading the file for data::::::  ");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String aLine = null;

    Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(aLine);
        if(aLine.trim().length()!=12)
        {
            System.out.println("Not a Valid number at line --->"+(i+1));
            continue;
        }
        //numberList.add(aLine.trim());
        i++;


    }
    Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    log.debug("Total Number/Row found in the file is  --> " + i);
}
```

Comment: can't you add a counter in your while loop? from 1-10000. When counter reaches 10000, you perform your operation and then set the counter to 0 again till your file ends. Understood?

Comment: Faraz, how do I add a counter to count till 1000 when in while loop I have mentioned (aLine = br.readLine()) != null. This while loop will check till the end.

Comment: Going good. See it this way. (aLine = br.readLine()) != null, this statement keep the while loop on till the end of file is not reached. 
1) Take an integer initialized to 0. 
2) Wait till it gets to 10000 (means 10000 lines are now in buffer)
3) Perform whatever operation you want on those 10000 line.
4) Free buffer memory and set the counter to 0 again.
This way you will be able to work on those 10000 lines, one by one, because your will be freeing the memory after operation and there will be no exception errors. Remember you have to do you operation inside while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Do not store all the lines in a `List` or any other structure and just treat them *on-the-fly*.

For instance in your case:

```
int nRows = 0;
int numbers = 0;
while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(aLine.trim().length() == 12) {
        numbers++;
    }
    nRows++;
}
log.debug("Total number of rows: " + nRows);
log.debug("Total number of line of length 12: " + numbers);
```

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` returns the amount of free memory in the Java Virtual Machine. I think he wanted to use `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()`.

Comment: Yes, I deleted my side note

Comment: Hi Vakh, thanks for the solution but I actually have put this data into a map and then process the map. Here in while loop I am taking aLine till !=null. I am not getting how to run this loop till a specified line and then after processing again set the counter to zero. Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using your fixed buffer approach You can consider using memory-mapped files, via FileChannels and can use   java.nio packages - those are supposedly faster than java.io,

This is link to article which have both approach explained,fixed buffer approach  and
 memory-mapped files with nio:

[Read a large file in chunks with fixed size buffer](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/01/3-ways-to-read-files-using-java-nio/)